# If your question is closed as a duplicate, should you delete it?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Sometimes you don't search for the answer to a question before you ask it. It will be closed as duplicate. Should you, the question owner, delete it? While it is good for search engines finding the answer and whatnot, it does take up space on the front page, pushing better questions down. What should be done in this situation?

Comment: Oh, the irony .

Comment: Is that irony? It tastes like deliberateness to me. It's certainly excellently illustrative.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson wasn't done on purpose

Comment: It's still excellently illustrative, for which I commend you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, leave it in place. Someone might phrase a search along similar lines as the formulation of your question. They find your duplicate and are lead to the main post. That can only ever be positive.